# Cut data off and plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a data file with 2300 data points. The data fluctuates between -0.1 to 0.1
I want to plot portions of the plot before it hits the value 0.1 again. For example:
if the first point is 0.1 then plot it till it hits 0.1 again and then stop..
and do the same after again . So, far I haven't been able to achieve that. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
G_Data = load('sample3.txt');
time = G_Data(:,1);
Ax = G_Data(:,2);
Ay = G_Data(:,3);
Az = G_Data(:,4);

%% Data parsing
ind = find(Az< 0.1& Az>-0.1);
nAz = Az(ind);
ntime = time(ind);
figure
plot(ntime,nAz)

%plot(ntime(1:197),nAz(1:197))'
```

I want the number (197) in this case because that is where first time the data set hits the value of about 0.1 to be found by the code.

*This is the current plot:*

[image: current]

*This is the desired plot:*

[image: desired]

Here is the link to the data file 
[DataFileTest](http://www.filedropper.com/sample3)

Comment: I put a link to the file with images, the first plot has those weird gaps in between. the second one is the desired plot. I want to cut off data as soon as the code sees the flat lines on top , plot it and do the same thing for the following data in there

Comment: The 'weird flat lines' are areas where you don't have any data.  Plot with `'*'` or other format commands to see.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I was able to clean that up and have proper parabola or the curve showing up !

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that the easiest way (though probably not the most computationally efficient) would be to split your data into different arrays as follows:

```
%make a cell to hold your arrays
outarrays = {};

%initialise a sub-array counter
subarray = 1;

%loop over all datapoints
for datapoint = 1 : length (Az)
    outarrays{datapoint} = [];
    if Az(datapoint) < 0.1
        outarrays{subarray}[end+1] = Az(datapoint);
    else
        %move on to next sub-array
        subarray = subarray + 1;
    end
    datapoint = datapoint + 1;
end
```

Then is is simple to plot the nth subarray using

```
cumulative_time = 0;
for subarray = 1 : n - 1
    cumulative_time = cumulative_time + length(outarray{subarray});
end
plot(time(cumulative_time : cumulative_time + length(outarray{n})),outarray{n});
```

I know it's full of loops which aren't very efficient in matlab, but with only a few thousand points it should run in very little time. Please check the code - I've got no appropriate data to test it on.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I am going to give it a try, where do I load in the file that I want to test in this code ?

Comment: I was assuming you loaded your data using the first 5 lines of the snippet you posted...

Comment: Where do I get the value for n? it is defined nowhere in the whole code

Comment: No, I clearly say what `n` is - I quote '...it is simple to plot the nth subarray...'. You just need to predefine `n` to be the number of the subset of data you want to plot...

Comment: yes I did that already before asking you the question, any value for n evaluates to this errror: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
Error in Untitled (line 30)
plot(time(cumulative_time : cumulative_time + length(outarrays{n}),outarrays{n}));

Comment: I think I've fixed it - I'd made a bracketting error on the last line, so it was passing an array index as an array itself causing the error. I've updated the code in my answer...

Comment: I used the code and still the same error. Is there a way to attach my data file here so you can test it out?

Comment: If you upload your datafile to dropbox (or similar) and post a public link to it on here I'll have a look at it...

Comment: I already put a link in the original post , its titled "DataFile"

Comment: Were you able to look into it?

Comment: I'm afraid the link you posted just takes me to the filedropper homepage - there doesn't appear to be a data file there...

Comment: The link expired as it was there for few days, I just put a new one

Comment: it's quite simple - you wanted code that would scan Az and split it up when it reaches its peak at 0.1. Thing is, Az is always greater than 0.1, so it never triggers.

Comment: There are many peaks which are not greater than 0.1 .. and what is where I am trying to cut the data off . The code that I wrote myself tells me these peaks but I couldn't figure out how to find the maximum out of those.. because of the same reasoning that you are saying . Any way around it ? to add more I am basically trying to figure out the parabola shape from the data set